# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 2} (x^3-4x)/|x^3-2x^2-x+2|$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x\to 2} (x^3-4x)/|x^3-2x^2-x+2|$
(If someone could help format that please :S)

I know the limit does not exist. How do I show this? I've found the intervals of $x^3 - 2x^2 - x+2$. I've tried searching for a solution, but examples I've seen don't involve an absolute value of a polynomial. Help would be appreciated?

Comment: Maybe L'Hopital Rule?

Comment: Not allowed to use that :/

Comment: factor both numerator and denominator, cancel the $x-2$ factors, watch out for the absolute value.The limit from the left and the limit from the right are likely two opposite numbers, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: How do I know which is the right and left hand limit?

Answer (score 3):

Take the left side and the right side limit and show that they are different.
From the negative side the bottom is negative so the bottom becomes negative
$\lim_{x\to 2-} \frac{x(x+2)(x-2)}{-(x-2)(x-1)(x+1)} = \lim_{x\to 2-} \frac{x(x+2)}{-(x-1)(x+1)} = -8/3$

$\lim_{x\to 2+} \frac{x(x+2)}{(x-1)(x+1)} = 8/3$

Since left and right limits are not same $\Rightarrow$ limit does not exist

Comment: Why infer that bottom is negative from left?

Comment: When you absolute a function, the part where it goes below the x axis will have to be multiplied by a -1 so that it becomes positive. Remember absolute values cannot be negative. In this case the function is negative when it approaches from the negative side of 2 and positive when it approaches from the postive side of 2. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

The limit from the right is $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{(x^3-4x)}{|x^3-2x^2-x+2|}= $
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{x(x-2)(x+2)}{|(x-2)(x^2-1)|}= $
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{x(x-2)(x+2)}{(x-2)(x^2-1)}= $
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{x(x+2)}{(x^2-1)}= $
$\displaystyle \frac{8}{3}$

On the other hand the limit from the left is 
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{(x^3-4x)}{|x^3-2x^2-x+2|}= $
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{x(x-2)(x+2)}{|(x-2)(x^2-1)|}= $
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{x(x-2)(x+2)}{(2-x)(x^2-1)}= $
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{-x(x+2)}{(x^2-1)}= $
$\displaystyle \frac{-8}{3}$.

Since
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{(x^3-4x)}{|x^3-2x^2-x+2|}= 
\frac{8}{3}\not = 
\frac{-8}{3} = \lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{(x^3-4x)}{|x^3-2x^2-x+2|}$, it follows that 
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{(x^3-4x)}{|x^3-2x^2-x+2|}$ does not exist.